# Printing number into words

Tags: c++, numbers, cpu-word

I have written a program to display numbers from 0-9999 into words. The program is working properly but I am experiencing unexpected output when I enter numbers from 11-19 and numbers like, 415,612,819 (basically all numbers that include 0-19 at the end). The program I have written is in c++ and I am currently beginner in c++.

```
//This program converts number into words
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int number,unit,ten,hundred,thousand;
    cout<<"Please enter any number between 0-9999: ";
    cin>>number;
    thousand=number/1000;
    number=number%1000;
    hundred=number/100;
    number=number%100;
    ten=number/10;
    number=number%10;
    unit=number;
    if(number>=11 && number <=19)
     {
        if(number==11) cout<<"eleven";
        if(number==12) cout<<"twelve";  
        if(number==13) cout<<"thirteen";
        if(number==14) cout<<"fourteen";
        if(number==15) cout<<"fifteen";
        if(number==16) cout<<"sixteen";
        if(number==17) cout<<"seventeen";
        if(number==18) cout<<"eighteen";
        if(number==19) cout<<"ninteen";
     }
    else
    {    
    if(thousand>=1 && thousand <=9)
    {
        if(thousand==1) cout<<"one thousand";
        if(thousand==2) cout<<"two thousand";
        if(thousand==3) cout<<"three thousand";
        if(thousand==4) cout<<"four thousand";
        if(thousand==5) cout<<"five thousand";
        if(thousand==6) cout<<"six thousand";
        if(thousand==7) cout<<"seven thousand";
        if(thousand==8) cout<<"eight thousand";
        if(thousand==9) cout<<"nine thousand";
    }
    if(hundred>=1 && hundred <=9)
    {
        if(hundred==1) cout<<" one hundred";
        if(hundred==2) cout<<" two hundred";
        if(hundred==3) cout<<" three hundred";
        if(hundred==4) cout<<" four hundred";
        if(hundred==5) cout<<" five hundred";
        if(hundred==6) cout<<" six hundred";
        if(hundred==7) cout<<" seven hundred";
        if(hundred==8) cout<<" eight hundred";
        if(hundred==9) cout<<" nine hundred";
    }
    if(ten>=1 && ten <=9)
    {
        if(ten==1) cout<<" ten";
        if(ten==2) cout<<" twenty";
        if(ten==3) cout<<" thirty";
        if(ten==4) cout<<" fourty";
        if(ten==5) cout<<" fifty";
        if(ten==6) cout<<" sixty";
        if(ten==7) cout<<" seventy";
        if(ten==8) cout<<" eighty";
        if(ten==9) cout<<" ninty";
    }
    if(unit>=1 & unit <=9)
    {
        if(unit==1) cout<<" one";
        if(unit==2) cout<<" two";
        if(unit==3) cout<<" three";
        if(unit==4) cout<<" four";
        if(unit==5) cout<<" five";
        if(unit==6) cout<<" six";
        if(unit==7) cout<<" seven";
        if(unit==8) cout<<" eight";
        if(unit==9) cout<<" nine";
    }
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
Please enter any number between 0-9999: 14
 ten four
```

Output:-

```
Please enter any number between 0-9999: 114
 one hundred ten four
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: `number=number%10;` won't produce a number larger than 9 so `if(number>=11 && number <=19)` is never true.

Comment: This looks very similar to code that has been posted by several different accounts over the last few days. If those are your coursemates, perhaps it's time for a get-together?

Comment: Yes, they are actually my classmates.

Comment: i suggest you to sit together in front of one pc and learn how to use a debugger. On the long term this will be better for you than asking the same question over and over again.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here you set `number` to be between `0` and `9`, so far so good:

```
number=number%10;
```

But then you are checking whether it is between `11` and `19`. That's not possible:

```
if(number>=11 && number <=19)
```

Due to this, the whole block will just be skipped and instead the last two blocks match, giving you "ten four". That first block should probably be something such as

```
if((ten==1) && (number>0))
{
    if(number==1) cout<<"eleven";
    if(number==2) cout<<"twelve";  
    if(number==3) cout<<"thirteen";
    if(number==4) cout<<"fourteen";
    if(number==5) cout<<"fifteen";
    if(number==6) cout<<"sixteen";
    if(number==7) cout<<"seventeen";
    if(number==8) cout<<"eighteen";
    if(number==9) cout<<"ninteen";
 }
```

Comment: It did solved my issue of printing numbers from 11-19 but numbers like 114 are giving still wrong output, like "114" is converted into "fourteen"

Comment: @Xacer Go through your program step by step. Either with a debugger or with your mind. Write down what the value of `number` is after every line and what each `if` will do. You will easily find why this problem happens. Every single one of the questions you (and your classmates?) have asked here are very easily solved like that, and this is an **essential** skill for programming.

Answer (score 1):

I re-write your entire code to make it short and easy to understand. Plus I included a function to re-use codes. I hope it will help you.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

std::string cast_to_str(int, int);

int main(){
    int num;
    std::cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    std::cin >>num;
    if(num / 1000)
        std::cout<<cast_to_str(num / 1000, 1)<<" thousand ";
    if((num = num % 1000) / 100)
        std::cout<<cast_to_str(num / 100, 1)<<" hundred ";
    if((num = num % 100) == 10)
        std::cout<<"ten"<<std::endl;
    else if(num > 10){
        if(num > 10 && num <= 19)
            std::cout<<cast_to_str(num / 10, 2)<<std::endl;
        else{
            std::cout<<cast_to_str(num/10, 3);
            if(num % 10)
                std::cout<<cast_to_str(num%10, 1)<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if(num)
        std::cout<<cast_to_str(num, 1)<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}

std::string cast_to_str(int num, int which){
    switch(num){
        case 1: return which == 1 ? "one"   : "eleven";
        case 2: return which == 1 ? "two"   : (which == 2 ? "twelve"    : "twenty ") ;
        case 3: return which == 1 ? "three" : (which == 2 ? "thirteen"  : "thirty ") ;
        case 4: return which == 1 ? "four"  : (which == 2 ? "fourteen"  : "fourty ") ;
        case 5: return which == 1 ? "five"  : (which == 2 ? "fifteen"   : "fifty ")  ;
        case 6: return which == 1 ? "six"   : (which == 2 ? "sixteen"   : "sixty ")  ;
        case 7: return which == 1 ? "seven" : (which == 2 ? "seventeen" : "seventy ");
        case 8: return which == 1 ? "eight" : (which == 2 ? "eighteen"  : "eighty ") ;
        case 9: return which == 1 ? "nine"  : (which == 2 ? "nineteen"  : "ninety ") ;
    }
}
```